# Is there a PRNG algorithm that allows to switch between states directly, not calling next()?

Tags: random-number-generator

Basically I need a function with the following interface:

```
getRandomBytes(uint128 seed, uint64 state, uint16 byteCount)
```

Consecutive calls with the same seed and state must give the same results.

What algorithm should I look at?

Comment: Perhaps a stream cipher with nonce support (e.g. AES-CTR, Salsa20, ChaCha, or any [eStream contestant](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/))? Or if the output size is limited, a hash should work as well.

Comment: What is the difference between seed and state? Do you need to also be able to get the current state?

Comment: @otus Ah, now I see, yes, I guess you should take the seed and state together. Do you need a 64 bit state, or can more information be transmitted?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yeah, you're right, I should concatenate them. "State" is basically coordinates. The function is used to generate random world content. Same coordinates = same content. Changing the seed should change the whole world.

Comment: @alain_morel: Maybe you can just use a decent keyed hash function to map unique inputs to pseudo-random values.  [SipHash](https://131002.net/siphash/) may work here, but if security is not a requirement I bet even a non-cryptographic hash like [MurmurHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) would work. [This blog entry](http://blog.demofox.org/2013/07/06/the-incredible-time-traveling-random-number-generator/) and [this one](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/RuneSkovboJohansen/20150105/233505/A_Primer_on_Repeatable_Random_Numbers.php) I just found on Google are illustrative.

Comment: @LuisCasillas thanks for the articles. All of these algorithms produce 64 bit output, when I need hundreds of bytes. Maybe it's expandable, but I'm afraid I will mess it up.

Comment: If it's "just" random world content, you might not need a cryptographically safe PRNG. Well, unless it's imperative that someone can't calculate the location of the hidden vault from the pattern of trees around their home... But in any case perhaps some security can/should be traded off for speed here.

Comment: @ilkkachu Given that the input, output and algorithm are public (or can be leaked), attacks are very likely. The advantage of a player who knows what items a monster will drop is unacceptable. But maybe the quality of the produced data is enough. Currently I'm testing xxhash algorithm. Even though its output is only 8 bytes, I can add a counter to the input and call the function n times. It's twice faster than AES and 20 times faster than SHAKE-256 (a java implementation).

Comment: @alain_morel: There are techniques for extending the output from 64 bits to larger, like: (a) adding a counter at the end of your coordinates for each 64-bits that you want, or (b) using that 64-bit value to seed a PRNG (though with non-cryptographic PRNGs you want to pay some attention there to whether this gives you uncorrelated sequences).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the easiest one with regards to the protocol is a XOF, an eXtendable Output Function. Two have been defined as part of SHA-3, called SHAKE-128 and SHAKE-256. These have a single input of any length, and can output as many bytes as required.

Of course SHA-3 is relatively new, so not all runtimes / API's may support the SHAKE variants out of the box.

---

In your case you would feed it the 128 bit seed concatenated with the 64 bit state. There should be no need for two separate variables.

Answer (score 4):

A [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher) may do the trick; you'd use your "seed" as key and your "state" as nonce, and just output a prefix of the keystream.  Currently popular ones are AES in [CTR mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) and [ChaCha20](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539).

Comment: Note that most stream ciphers are designed to be used with random keys. So if your seeds aren't random, you might need to hash them first.

Answer (score 4):

This has been said by others, but I wanted to stress it more. The input sizes you are looking at all fit into AES with the (random) seed as the key and the "state" together with a counter $i$ that goes from $0$ and up to $\frac{\rm byteCount}{16}$ concatenated as the input (with additional fixed zeroes). AES is assumed to behave as a pseudorandom permutation and so this will give you a very high quality pseudorandom string each time.

AES is also much faster than using something like SHA-3. However, I want to stress that although SHA-3 and in fact all cryptographic hash functions are designed to have "random looking behavior" this is not their main design principle. They are designed to first and foremost be collision resistant, and then to behave "randomly" as a secondary design principle. In contrast, block ciphers are designed to behave pseudorandomly. As such, they are the preferred primitive of choice in these cases. Note that I am not saying that you cannot use a hash function for such purposes. However, I would typically go for it only when there's a reason not to use something like AES. In this specific case, there is no reasons (and it would be even faster).

Finally, regarding AES vs something like ChaCha20: again, being conservative, AES has undergone much more cryptanalytic scrutiny than ChaCha20 so I prefer it. If you have AES-NI hardware support then it's also well fast enough. If not, and speed is very critical then you may wish to consider something like ChaCha20.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I tried AES and it's really much faster than SHAKE.

Comment: @alain_morel Current Oracle Java and OpenJDK's use AES-NI to speed things up (and the bytecode has been optimized a lot too) so that AES is faster than SHAKE is not really a surprise. Keccak needs more attention and hardware support to get to the same level. In principle the amount of passes = 1 in both cases.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for information. At first I chose SHAKE because it looked simplier. But after some reading I made AES work (providing predefined initialization vector), and the speed difference is huge.

Comment: After more testing it appears that the output of processing 2 similar inputs (i.e. 1 bit difference) differs very little, not by 50%. Is it intended or I'm doing something wrong?